# unable to show date with correct time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm setting in another section that it saves with `curdate()`; the date into a DB after that I want to list the value in a table with its time but when I try to make it this way:

```
echo "<td style='width: 15%;'>". date("d.m.Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['Erstelldatum'])) . '</td>';
```

I'm getting this:
[image]

The format is right (German) but the time is not correct. What is wrong here? Is the DB format wrong?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the data in the database is correct? (Please update your question to show an example of what's being stored or, better still, how you're storing it.)

Comment: What is structure of your table?

Comment: Are you sure that time data is in your database?  Or, is it just dates?

Comment: Looks more like a `date` field than `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field type in database must be `DATETIME`. Your current type is `DATE`.

Comment: This is what I would look at aswell.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. Had to do some light modifications in the whole process of filling the data. Now its working :)